# how can i access to the entity repository from a entity listener in symfony 2.8?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, listener

I'm new in Symfony 2.

I have a function called "addNewTarjeta" in a personalized entity respository.

```
<?php

namespace Elkanogroup\ClientesBundle\Repository;

/**
 * ClienteRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class ClienteRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository {

 /**
     * Asigna una tarjeta a este cliente. 
     */
    public function addNewTarjeta(Cliente $cliente) {
        $tarjeta = new \Elkanogroup\ClientesBundle\Entity\Tarjeta();

        $tarjeta->setNumeroTarjeta('5555 5555 5555 5555');
        $tarjeta->setCliente($cliente);
        $tarjeta->setFechaExpedicion(new \DateTime());

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();        
        $em->persist($tarjeta);
        $flush = $em->flush();

        if ($flush != null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

I have a listener waiting for a doctrine event postPersist. I would like to call to "addNewTarjeta" from a postPersist function.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Elkanogroup\ClientesBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Elkanogroup\ClientesBundle\Entity\Cliente;
use Elkanogroup\ClientesBundle\Repository\ClienteRepository;

class ClienteListener {



    public function postPersist(Cliente $cliente, LifecycleEventArgs $args) {


        $cliente->addNewTarjeta($cliente);
    }
```

But it doesnt  work. **Symfony says:**

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "addNewTarjeta" of class
>   "Elkanogroup\ClientesBundle\Entity\Cliente".

Can anyone help me ?? Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You need to inject doctrine into your listener class.

Comment: Thanks, I'm begginer how can I do that?

Comment: Just like Oscar Pérez showed in his answer. ;-)

Comment: You can also read the docs...

Answer (score 3):

Everyone here says that you need to inject the entity manager but to me it's not true: you can retrive it from `LifecycleEventArgs` without inject anything.

Just do

```
$args->getObjectManager();
```

and you're done.

Just a note: *usually* repos are used to keep custom queries (via DQL or plain SQL or query builder). A logic like this *should* be fitted inside a service (a manager, helper or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to do that, but the symofny request is the same. Inserting the function into a entity class its work, but i suppose it not correct.

Comment: Thanks @DonCallisto ! You were right! I acces to enttiy manager doing: $em = $args->getEntityManager();  and  to use the method I needed to
$repository = $em->getRepository('ElkanogroupClientesBundle:Cliente'); $repository ->addNewTarjeta(); Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

As @dragoste said, you need to inject the `entitymanager` service into your listener.

It can be done in `services.yml`:

```
  name.of.your.listener:
    class: AppBundle\Listener\MyListener
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

And then, add a `public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager)` method in your listener:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Listener;

class MyListener
{
  /**
   * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
   */
  private $entityManager;

  public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager)
  {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but it doesn't work for me. Now symfony says:  Type error: Argument 1 passed to Elkanogroup\ClientesBundle\EventListener\ClienteListener::__construct() must be an instance of Elkanogroup\ClientesBundle\EventListener\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /home/silken/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/DefaultEntityListenerResolver.php on line 73

Comment: Did you modified file `services.yml`? Are you using `yml` or `xml` for service's description?

Comment: Regardless of what he does, it won't work.  You will get a circular dependency error since the manager depends on it's listeners.  Try it.  Be sure to tag the listener properly.

Comment: Yes. I modified it. Im using yml. Thanks.

Comment: As @Cerad says, you'll get a circular dependency error. Try DonCallisto answer instead, and excuse-me for my wrong answer

Comment: This gave me 500 headaches, literally and HTTPally.